# Как в ruby-openCV расчитать медиану изображения

Tags: ruby, opencv

Есть код на python:

```
median = np.median(img)
```

Искал что-то похожее в ruby - не нашел.
Подскажите аналог для ruby, возможно есть отдельная либа для этого.

Comment: на питоне это точно из `OpenCV`, а не из `numpy`?

Comment: Точно, сейчас поищу такую-же для ruby, спасибо